# post the form and again load the view ,best suggested way

Tags: codeigniter

Till now i am using the form post method like this::

controller ::

```
public function loading_view()
{
.
.
.
.
$this->load->view('abc');

}
```

view abc:

">

when this form posted it will redirected to

```
public function method_of_controller()
{

.
//perform query 
.
// here i am havin 2 way to call
//1.

$this ->load->view('abc');

//and 2.

load->loading_view();
}
```

//bu url remain same after the post method like `....index.php/loading_view`

and but on reloading the page again the query runs fr 2nd method of loading view
so which way you will suggest me to use best

Answer (score 0):

1- If you are not passing data to your view and your view is just contains html and javascript
than first method is beter.
2- if you are passing data to our abc view page than second is beter.
3- beter way is to make another view for this part for portability
because in some point you will reach you make changes so it is beter to each should be 
separate.

Comment: ya but if i am usign 2nd one...but the url bar will show the url of this method... and if suppose i reload the page...unnecessarily the unwanted data will get submitted agin..

Comment: Make another view for this method.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can post data to save view, without changing url redirection, in following way

**controller**

```
class PostTest extends CI_Controller{

 public function loading_view()
{
$this->form_validation->rules('name','Name','required');
if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
  $this->load->view('abc');
}
else{
      $name = $this->input->post('name');
}

}

}
```

now here is most interesting part is view in form action you need to use uri_string() method like this

**view**

```
<? echo form_open(uri_string())
  .form_input('name').br()
  .form_error('name')
  .form_submit('submit','Post data'); 
 ?>
```